# How to remove email scope and add ONLY youtube.readonly scope using Firebase GoogleAuthProvider

Tags: angular, firebase, google-oauth, angularfire2

I try to use Firebase and Angular 2 to validate user into my app and get user YouTube Channel information. Here is my code:

```
   return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    let provider = new firebase.auth.GoogleAuthProvider();
    let token: any;
    let fullData: any;
    provider.addScope('https://www.googleapis.com/auth/youtube.readonly');
    firebase.auth().signInWithPopup(provider).then(result => {
      token = result.credential.accessToken;

      fullData = {
        uid: (result.user.uid || ""),
        photoURL: (result.user.photoURL || ""),
        name: (result.user.displayName || ""),
        youtube_channel: {}
      }

      let headers = new Headers();
      let googleAPI = "https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/channels?part=brandingSettings%2C+snippet%2C+id%2C+statistics&mine=true";
      headers.append('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
      headers.append('Content-Type', 'application/json');

      return this.http.get(googleAPI, { headers })
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          fullData.youtube_channel = data;

          return this.userProfile.child(fullData.uid).update(fullData).then(_ => {
            resolve(fullData);
          });

        })
    }).catch(err => {
      console.error(err);
      resolve();
    })
  });
```

The problem is when run this code, it works and get the info I need and log the user in. But google ask users for Email, profile, and YouTube read permission. I only want Profile and YouTube read permission BUT NOT email - I don't want the Oauth window popup by google ask for users' email at all.

In Firebase there is ONLY provider.addScope('...'), but can I remove email scope (which is the default scope I guess?). Firebase experts, please help!

Answer (score 1):

The `email` scope is actually automatically added by Firebase and cannot be removed.

I would suggest to use Google Sign-In library `gapi.auth2` and the `signInWithCredential` method of Firebase. This way you'll be able to customize the scopes as you want.

You can follow the code example [here](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-credentials.html) to see how to integrate Google Sign-In library with Firebase.

You will have to add this:

`<meta name="google-signin-fetch_basic_profile" content="false">`

below [there](https://github.com/firebase/quickstart-js/blob/master/auth/google-credentials.html#L35) in the file. This will disable automatically adding `email profile openid` as scopes. Then update the `"google-signin-scope"` meta tag to only ask for `openid profile` and the YouTube scope you require. `openid` is required for Firebase to be able to load the profile of the user.

You will have to whitelist the origin in the [developers console](https://console.developers.google.com/). Go to Api Manager > Credentials, look for the Web Client ID under OAuth 2.0 Client ID. Click on it, and you will be able to add your app's origin.

Let me know if that works!

Comment: This is too complicated and went way over my head... I am looking for some native Firebase solution to just do that for me instead of rolling out my own Google single sign in. The reason I use Firebase is to NOT do that at all...Is there no other way?

Comment: Great starting point thanks. I'm gonna have a go for an implementation. I will report back if it works out.

Comment: So using the api ive only set the scope to be scope='openid' however when inspecting the authResponse the scope is this : ""https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.email https://www.googleapis.com/auth/userinfo.profile https://www.googleapis.com/auth/plus.me openid""

Comment: It always seems to override, the email is always present. But most of the other profile data is absent.